# c# NReco.VideoConverter Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c#, linux, ffmpeg, nreco

I'm trying to use the functionality of the NReso library. VideoConverter. The program is launched from Ubuntu OS 16.04 in the MonoDevelopment environment. The operating system is 64 charging. I installed the application FFMpeg and it works fine.
And I have a problem that does not make a lot of sense. I'm trying to use code NReso.VideoConveter from the site official site https://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx :

```
try
{
     string [] paths = {"1.mp4",
     "1.mp4",
     "1.mp4"};
     ConcatSettings concatSettings = new ConcatSettings ();
     concatSettings.ConcatAudioStream = false;
     concatSettings.ConcatVideoStream = true;
     FFMpegConverter ffMpegConvert = new FFMpegConverter ();
     Console.WriteLine ("Converting ... \ r \ n");
     ffMpegConvert.ConcatMedia (paths, "3.mp4", Format.mp4, concatSettings);
     Console.WriteLine ("Complete!");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
}
```

The code produces an error of type

> "ApplicationName = '/ home / neytchi / Projects / testVE / testVE /
>   bin / Debug / ffmpeg.exe', CommandLine = '- y -loglevel info -i
>   "1.mp4" -i "1.mp4" -i "1. mp4 "-f mp4 -filter_complex" concat = n = 3:
>   v = 1 [v] "-map" [v] "" 3.mp4 "', CurrentDirectory =' / home / neytchi
>   / Projects / testVE / testVE / bin / Debug ', Native error = Access
>   denied" or so  "Unhandled Exception: Systems
>   .ComponentModel.Win32Exception"

I can not understand the cause of problem, but I'm assuming that the library starts the process as 32-bit, when everything else is 64-bit.
Any ideas? Perhaps someone met with a similar on Ubuntu.

Comment: I wonder if the content of the `paths` variable is right. Perhaps the problem is that it tries to read multiple times the same file because of that paths value and second file read raises the access denied error ('cause the first reading locks the file).

Comment: Have you tried copying the `1.mp4` file into new files and setting different paths? Something like `string[] paths = {"1_1.mp4", "1_2.mp4", "1_3.mp4"}`

Comment: I tried to create files and change paths to "string [] paths = {" 1_1.mp4 "," 1_2.mp4 "," 1_3.mp4 "}" - the error did not change.

Comment: I get to start the video processing of FFmpeg, like this:
    Process process = new Process ();
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo ();
    info.UseShellExecute = true;
    info.Arguments = "-version";
    process.StartInfo = info;
    process.Start ();
But I would like to use the functionality of the library. This would simplify my task.

Comment: I solved question by edit path to the installed ffmpeg and rename exe from "ffmpeg" to "ffmpeg.exe".